# Is "drain the swamp" an idiomatic expression exclusively used by Americans?

Tags: idioms, american-english

Now the expression "drain the swamp" is often heard on TV and the internet,especially during the 2016 US presidential campaign.

The meaning of this expression is not hard to grasp, but I am not sure if it is an idiomatic expression mostly used by Americans.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding etymology are [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Max, the question has been edited.

Comment: @mike, the question has been edited.